# How to know if I'm looking at the source data or a downsampled overview/pyramid in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mapping, rendering, image-pyramids, map-overviews

If I build overviews/pyramids on a GeoTIFF, when I'm viewing the data in QGIS, is there an easy way to know if I'm looking at the source data or one of the overviews/pyramids? Not sure where the accurate (non-downsampled) source data begins and ends when zooming.

Comment: There is a "Zoom to native resolution (100%)" option when you right click on the layer, so  this will show you the scale at witch you are looking at source data, if you zoom in or out some resampling will happen...

Comment: Thank you. Curious why would resampling happen as you zoom in if it's already at the source data at a higher zoom level?

Comment: Yes when you zoom-in past the native resolution either you see individual pixel (so still source data but in big "pixel") or some resampling happen to have a less pixelated look, this depend on your setting, QGIS let you choose different resampling method for zooming in and out